# Quiero ejecutar dos setInterval dentro del useEffect pero el primer setInterval no funciona, alguien sabe porque no y como solucionarlo?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

Aqui esta el codigo que he utilizado. Uso un useEffect que se ejecuta en cada render y el cual crea dos intervalos. El primer intervalo no funciona y creo que es porque en el segundo utilizo el método setAmount para actualizar una variable y mostrarla por pantalla actualizada y vuelve a renderizar el componente, pero como podría hacer que funcionase el primer setInterval?

```
 useEffect(() => {
        // save the player automatically every minute
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            savePlayer(player, amount)
            console.log('Saving player automatically...')
        }, 2000)

        const interval2 = setInterval(() => {
            let am: number = 0;
            for(let i = 0; i < player.improves.length; i++){
                am += player.improves[i].num * player.improves[i].amountGenerated
            }
            setAmount(amount + am)
        }, 1000)

        // save the player when keydown ALT + S
        const save = (event: any) => {
            if(event.altKey && event.key === 's'){
                savePlayer(player, amount)
                console.log('Saving player...')
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('keydown', save)
        
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', save); 
            clearInterval(interval);
            clearInterval(interval2);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, de acuerdo al codigo los intervalos se cancelan cuando se desmonta el componente que esta usando ese `useEffect`, en teoria deberian dispararse ambos intervalos, ¿Porque dices que el primero no funciona? Hay que elaborar un poco mas el problema